# Как не указывать на каждый файла в .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно прописать в .htaccess, чтобы не указывать на каждый файл например: ../../img, а указать просто /img?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам, очевидно, нужен mod_rewrite.

См. http://habrahabr.ru/post/83597/ , http://habrahabr.ru/post/154643/ и http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html